# how to replace specific record on a line containg a string with a number from another file using inplace editing sed in linux

Tags: linux, string, replace, sed

I have an input file  like following.

```
R sfst     1000.0000                                                            
$ new time step for mass scaled calculation
R dt2ms    -4.000E-7                                                            
$ friction value for blank
R mue       0.120000                                                            
$ blankholder force
R bhf      2.0000E+5                                                            
$ simulation time
R endtime   0.150000
```

i want to change the value on the line containing 'mue'
with following I can read it but cant change it.

```
awk ' /mue/ { print $3 } ' input.txt
```

The value is to be taken from another file fric.txt.
fric.txt contains only numbers, one on each line .

fric.txt has data like

```
0.1234
0.234
0.0234
```

.
.

> Blockquote

It should be noted that ONLY the FIRST instance need to be replaced and the format i.e. white spacing be kept cosntant.

> Blockquote

Can anybody guide me doing this using sed or awk?

Comment: Which line? A known, fixed line, like line 42?

Comment: no, it is the line with meu, could be anywhere

Comment: first line of fric.txt, then i delete the first line so that for the next iteration it take the next value and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/\<mue\>/!d;=;s/.* \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/;R fric.txt' input.txt |
sed 'N;N;s|\n|s/|;s|\n|/|;s|$|/|;q' >temp.sed
sed -i -f temp.sed input.txt
```

Comment: the problem is that , it continues to replace all the instance of meu and doesnt stop at the first instance. this is the problem.

Comment: please suggest for the change at only first instance.

Comment: OK just shorten the script to the first instance, see amended solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
$ awk '/mue/ && !seen {getline $3 <"fric.txt"; seen=1} 1' input.txt
```

Comment: in this case I have to pipe the file and the renmae it back to my input file. is it also possible with sed -i so that in place editing takes place and I need not to rename the file ? it does work but that would be elegant.

Comment: Side effect: You can `diff` them before renaming.

Comment: it changes the spacing in betweeen , I want to keep the format so that the software continue to recognize the format. can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: it also changes all the instance, i want to change only the first one

Comment: @hamaskhan, awk does not have anything like sed's `-i`, so you have to write to a temp file and then rename.

Comment: @kev, I took the liberty of updating your answer so that only the first instance is modified.

Comment: @glenn the problem is the same, it replace all the instance, I want to replace only the first one, and it must keep the format.. please suggest

Comment: @hamaskhan, I updated kev's answer. Also, if you have additional requirements (keep the format), you need to add them to your question.

Comment: @glenn this is perfect but the problem of format is still there.. I mean the software doesnt understand if the white spaces are not constant.

Comment: @hamaskhan, to keep the formatting, use `getline newval < "fric.txt"; sub(/[0-9.]+$/, newval)`

Comment: @glenn  as you told , I used         `awk '/mue/ && !seen {getline newval < "fric.txt"; sub(/[0-9.]+$/, newval); seen=1} 1' input.txt  > 1.k`   but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a sed in the sed (assuming you like to take line 1 from fric.txt):

```
sed -ir 's/(.*mue[ \t]+)[0-9.]+(.*)/\1'$(sed -n '1{p;q}' fric.txt)'\2/' input.txt
```

Comment: it ends up with an error  sed: -e expression #1, char 39: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: I don't get such an error. Did you copy and paste the command?

Comment: yes, direct in console and also in script. its the same error.